# Converting an array to positive indicator

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Suppose that we have an array like:

```
[-2,4,3,-1,2]
```

How can we convert this to the positive indicator array in `python` such that we have

```
[0,1,1,0,1]
```

I know how to do this in `MATLAB` but not in the `python`.

Comment: using `numpy` is it not exactly the same as in Matlab? This page thins so: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Comment: It returns a logical array. I think then I should just turn the logical array to `0,1` array. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you tagged this with numpy, I assume you want a solution based on that:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2,4,3,-1,2])
positive_indicator = np.int64(a > 0)
```

You can use whatever dtype you want for the result. So `np.int8` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2,4,3,-1,2])
np.where(a>0,1,0)
```

Comment: Until you explain how this code is supposed to work, -1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is numpy's [heaviside](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html#numpy.heaviside)-function

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2,4,3,-1,2])
np.heaviside(a, 0)

array([0., 1., 1., 0., 1.])
```

Note that the second argument in the heaviside function indicates how 0's are mapped

Answer (score 0):

```
In [188]: L = [-2,4,3,-1,2]

In [189]: [int(i>0) for i in L]
Out[189]: [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Lacks explanation. -1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [-2,4,3,-1,2]                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> map(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0, x)
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```